# Google Play: find traffic peaks

Tags: analytics, google-play-console

Is there a way to see in the Google Play console how many users at which time of the day were actively using my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment. If you want analytics like this then you probably want to add a solution like [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) to your app.